# Why do I get a SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference in inter

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Why does setting the disabled attribute in Internet Explorer not work? In Internet Explorer it outputs a error. In other browsers it does work. The error happens at line 6 and 7. The error it outputs is shown below:

> SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null references. sql.html(6, 1)

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            if (!window.openDatabase){
                alert("Sorry your browser dosent support WebSQL")
                document.getElementById("input").disabled = true
                document.getElementById("button").disabled = true
            } else {
                var db = openDatabase("mydb", 1.0, "mydb", 2*1024*1024)
                function execute(){
                    db.transaction(function (t){
                        t.executeSql(document.getElementById("input").value)
                        console.log(document.getElementById("input").value)
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <textarea id="input"></textarea>
        <button onclick="execute()" id="button">Execute SQL</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

However typing the code at line 6 and 7 in the console does work.
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page loaded from top to bottom, according to your code, when you use the getElementById method to get the textarea and button, they are not loaded. So, it can't find these controls, and will display the "Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null references" error.

You could put your code in the onload Event. The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded.

Please modify your code as below:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function pageload() { 
            if (!window.openDatabase) {
                alert("Sorry your browser dosent support WebSQL")
                document.getElementById("input").disabled = true
                document.getElementById("button").disabled = true
            } else {
                var db = openDatabase("mydb", 1.0, "mydb", 2 * 1024 * 1024)
                function execute() {
                    db.transaction(function (t) {
                        t.executeSql(document.getElementById("input").value)
                        console.log(document.getElementById("input").value)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body" onload="pageload();">
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <button onclick="execute()" id="button">Execute SQL</button>
</body>
```